# Android NDK - how to run tests using Catch C++ Test Framework

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, cmake, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests

How to configure cmake/gradle to quickly run tests using Catch Test Framework inside Android Studio? Ideally, with a single click or using a shortcut.